# Do I have to repaste Laptop CPU/GPU in the same way it was when I opened it?

Tags: thermal-paste

I have a gaming laptop and I have removed the heatsink and saw the paste literally everywhere. So the CPU has these resistor like things next to it, that had paste on them as well as the GPU (which l have cleaned).

When reapplying the paste would I need to repaste these as well as the CPU and GPU? The heat sink covers this whole area.

The paste is non conductive and non capacitive.

Comment: Only the chips should have thermal paste. If it was conductive you may have had serious problems.

Comment: Only the GPU/GPU (including their heatsink) should have thermal paste.  Sounds like either somebody either removed the heatsink and accidently touched other parts and mistakenly got paste on them or whom ever put the paste on last time was did it by mistake.